# Tableau collate data from multiple columns

Tags: tableau-api

I am not sure what the technical term for what I am trying to do is.
Hoping raw data and output below will clearly define the use case.

Raw data :
[This is what my raw data looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OV8o4.png)

Output 1 :
[this is what I am trying extract first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dAhA.png)
Here I am trying to get a table where the first column has the name of the guests and 2nd column has the count of times they have featured in the table as a guest.

Output 2 :
[this what I am trying extract next](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ID4I8.png)
Here I am trying to map months against names and see how many nights one has collected in which month.

One way to achieve this would be to create a temp table with 5 columns,
column 1 with Guest names,
column 2 with count of occurrence in guest 1 column in raw data table,
column 3 with count of occurrence in guest 2 column in raw data table,
column 4 with count of occurrence in guest 3 column in raw data table,
column 5 with total of previous 3 columns.

But I am trying to find a proper solution through tableau, if possible. Because this way would not help me achieve Output 2.

Plain text raw data if you'd like to work on it :
booking by,Guest 1,Guest 2,Guest 3,stay start,stay end,hotel code
Ram,Seema,Ram,,May 1 2018,May 2 2018,BBST
Karan,Ram,Seema,,May 6 2018,May 7 2018,BRRLY
Mahesh,Mahesh,Seema,Ram,June 2 2018,June 4 2018,BBST
Krishna,Krishna,,,June 2 2018,June 3 2018,BRRLY
Seema,Seema,,,June 7 2018,June 8 2018,BRRLY

Comment: try pivot of guest1, guest2 and guest3

Comment: Thank you, I used Tableau Prep to do a pivot like you mentioned.